# Use regular expression to remove text

Tags: regex

I have an xml file which I try to retrieve some information using linq to xml. There is a tag in the xml file that is like this

```
<description>
<img src='http://www.sport.gr//files/Image/2012/May/14/802.jpg'>Τραγική ήταν η παρουσία της Αστον Βίλα στη φετινή Πρέμιερ Λιγκ και.....
</description>
```

What I want to do is to retrieve the link inside src attribute using a regular expression. Any idea how I can achieve this? I cannot edit the format of xml because it comes from a web request.

Comment: Have you considered using an XML parser rather than messing with your own regexes?

Comment: I try to build a small windows phone application and i have finished everything i need except from this. Thank you for your answer..

Comment: Try libxml2, it's portable and easy to use :)

Comment: obLink: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern

```
<img.*\s+src=('(?<src>.*?)'|"(?<src>.*?)")
```

Extract the "src" group if there's a match.